# setting acl using gsutil on google cdn bucket via domain

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud, google-cdn

On documentation https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl#ch it says that this command `gsutil acl ch -g my-domain.org:R gs://gcs.my-domain.org` should grant access to users from domain `my-domain.org` but I am not sure if this means the referrer of the request to the bucket should have my-domain.org. Can you explain?

And if not then is there a way to protect contents against hotlinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that refers to users who are logged in with the Google Apps domain `@my-domain.org`.

There is currently no way to condition ACLs to prevent hotlinking.